# Updating list of string while other threads are reading from it

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, logging

I have a logging solution that writes down the hashes of messages. I consider some of these hashes to be safe and I want to skip logging those. I have implemented a whitelist that is a directory containing whitelisted hashes. There is a timer task that updates that list every 10 minutes.

I have tried testing it from multiple angles, but experience shows that it is near to impossible to generate the load with the diversity that I see in the wild. So could someone point out any shortcomings in my approach, only relevant parts showed:

```
public class MyLogger {

    private volatile AtomicReference<List<String>> whitelist = new AtomicReference<List<String>>();

    private void startWhitelistListener() {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateWhitelist();
                    }
                }, 1000, 60 * 10 * 1000
        );
    }

    private void updateWhitelist() {
        try{
            ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (File f : scriptWhitelistDirectory.listFiles()){
                tempList.add(f.getName());
            }
            whitelist.set(tempList);
        } catch (Throwable ignore){}
    }
....
}
```

Now there will be threads accessing the whitelist like:

```
if (whitelist.get().contains(hash)) return null;
```

Is the implementation thread safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if you *only read* the `whitelist`.

You can guarantee this at runtime by wrapping it in `Collections.unmodifiableList` while setting.

```
whitelist.set(Collections.unmodifiableList(tempList));
```

However because you don't use any other feature of the AtomicReference other than get and set, you don't need `AtomicReference` at all (or if you do it should be final); just `volatile` is enough:

```
private volatile List<String> whitelist = Collections.emptyList();//empty dummy list

whitelist = Collections.unmodifiableList(tempList);
```

And check with `if (whitelist.contains(hash)) return null;`

That leads me to the list itself; if you only check whether a values is contained within the list then you should consider changing the list to a HashSet.

```
private volatile Set<String> whitelist = Collections.emptySet();

Set<String> tempList = new HashSet<String>();
for (File f : scriptWhitelistDirectory.listFiles()){
    tempList.add(f.getName());
}
whitelist = Collections.unmodifiableSet(tempSet);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `volatile` is misguided, and it does nothing for you, in this situation. The fact that you have used `volatile` here indicates that you don't understand what it does, and why you may need it.

In general, with the availability of the `java.util.concurrent.*`, and traditional `synchronize`, there is no real reason to use `volatile` at all. `volatile` is a hard-to-see memory management technique that immediately rings alarm bells for me.

while ratchet freak's suggested implementation will work fine, I strongly advise against using `volatile` simply because it is too hard to see.

In your case, you never change the `whitelist`, so there is no purpose to the `volatile`. Sure, you change the contents inside the `whitelist`, but that's different. Further, your `whitelist` should be final, which would be better practice, and helps with concurrency too.

```
private final AtomicReference<List<String>> whitelist = new AtomicReference<>();
```

Note above how I use the `<>` 'diamond operator'. Using the full generic type on the right-hand- side of an assignment is no longer needed.

The `Atomic*` classes ensure that the memory model for get/set operations are correctly ordered, and thread safe. As a result, the way you get and set the List in that is currently just fine.

As ratchet freak indicates, you should probably be using a `Set`, and not a `List`. A set offers constant lookup times as your set size increases.

If it were me, I would have something like:

```
private final AtomicReference<Set<String>> whitelist = new AtomicReference<>(Collections.emptySet());

private void updateWhitelist() {
    try{
        Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for (File f : scriptWhitelistDirectory.listFiles()){
            tempList.add(f.getName());
        }
        whitelist.set(Collections.unmodifiableSet(tempList));
    } catch (Throwable neverIgnore){
        Logger.warn("Unable to read files from " + scriptWhitelistDirectory, neverIgnore);
    }
}
```

Note how I handle the exception too, even if it is just to log it somewhere.